# GA4 event value not showing up on the revenue report even if there's conversions already

Tags: google-analytics

I modify the event value on GA4 but on the conversion reports, no revenue value is showing up. Has anyone experienced this and solved the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue. What I have found so far is that:

1. Make sure you have a parameter named "value" as a number
2. Make sure you have a parameter named "currency". Currency of the items associated with the event, in 3-letter ISO 4217 format.

Now here is the catch. The Event name needs to be "purchase". In all the testing I did so far, only the purchase event passes the value to the Revenue column the reports. That said, you can still see the values for other events that have value in the Explorations.